# Network bandwidth usage dashboard?

Tags: bandwidth, wireless-networking

I have a couple of wifi access points hooked up to my home network, one of which I keep unsecured for some development I do; there are only a couple other homes within range and they've got their own wifi so it's not a big concern.  I also have a Sonos system, Tivo, Roku, a couple laptops, a couple phones, an iPad and a desktop machine, all of which are internet-smart.

So when my internet bandwidth tanks and it takes five minutes to load a YouTube video, I want to know what's going on, and there are many potential culprits.  I'd like to be able to plug my MacBook into the primary router and see a nice little dashboard of the units on the network and what kind of bandwidth each is using at that moment.  I could figure this out from WireShark or tcpdump but figure there has to be an easier way.  I've tried a few different commercial products but none really presented the right info.

Suggestions?  (This may be a question for superuser since my Apple Time Capsule's SNMP capabilities are limited, but I figure admins of small business networks would have dealt w/ the same issue..)

Comment: Business networks usually runs SNMP as well QoS, basically if your wifi is screwed, just use a good cable.

Answer (score 0):

I use Cacti and MRTG at home to graph bandwidth usage. If you have a box you can leave running to do the polling, it's hard to beat. Even the limited SNMP set on an APE can give you enough interface data to make coherent and relevant graphs.